# is it possible to install show hint add on in codemirror6

Tags: codemirror-6

When I am using this command to install the show hint plugin in codemirror 6:

```
 pnpm install @codemirror/show-hint
 ERR_PNPM_FETCH_404  GET https://registry.npmjs.org/@codemirror%2Fshow-hint: Not Found - 404
```

seems the show hint did not exists, am I missing something? is it possible to install this plugin?

Answer (score 2):

It should be installed in this way.

```html
import { javascript } from '@codemirror/lang-javascript'
import { python } from '@codemirror/lang-python'
import { sql } from '@codemirror/lang-sql'
import { java } from '@codemirror/lang-java'
```